# Burninate [fdisk] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There is an [fdisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fdisk) tag. Of the 40 questions, I see only three, maybe four, which could reasonably be placed on Stack Overflow rather than Super User, and those few don't really need an fdisk tag.

The tag almost always indicates that the user is asking on the wrong site.

Can we burninate [fdisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fdisk)? And maybe even move most of the questions to Super User?

Comment: Title suggestion - *Unmount this [fdisk]*

Comment: Or *disk format the [fdisk] tag*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, go ahead with burnination, though [none of the young-enough posts look like worth migrating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).
There are only <del>40</del> 2:

1. Edit the questions which are salvagable. **done**
2. [Downvote all unsalvagable unanswered questions to -1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfdisk%5D+score%3A0..+answers%3A0+closed%3A0) so the roomba gets them. **done**
3. [Close-vote everything left](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfdisk%5D+answers%3A1..+closed%3A0). **done**
4. [Downvote all closed questions without accepted answer or high-scoring answer (5+), and their answers to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfdisk%5D+answers%3A1..+closed%3A1+duplicate%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0), so the roomba gets them. **done**
5. [Delete-vote all closed questions not handled in the previous step](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfdisk%5D+closed%3A1+hasaccepted%3A1). **done**
6. Wait for the roomba to get te rest.

[CV-review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=fdisk) **done**

Comment: So now it's appropriate to downvote somebody just because his question is zero score and unanswered? :(

Comment: @user000001 Not quite. But if the question does not belong / cannot be salvaged, in some cases downvoting is the easiest way to get rid of it. You might have seen that the first step is saving what's useful. And I already saved some, you are welcome to help.

Comment: 8 left now. Mostly needing 1 or 2 delv votes. Will be done within 1 hr max.

Comment: [Done!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fdisk)

Comment: Almost 3 yrs later, mark [status-completed] **done**